# How to make language embedding when hit the domain of site

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I am using Sitecore with SXA, I need to embed a language to the URL. I know I can do it from configuration to make the `languageEmbedding=always`, but what I need is to add the language when I hit the domain of the site, like when I write **`https://{{domain}}/`** by default the "***en***" language to be embedded to the domain of the site. Is there any extra configuration to do that?

Comment: Did you try to change Language field in Site Grouping at this path: /sitecore/content/<TenantName>/<SiteName>/Settings/Site Grouping/<SiteName>

Comment: yes it is english by default, but the language not embeded in the url when open the domain url

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the language Embedding by using the configuration

```
languageEmbedding=always
```

Then you disable the other by using this tutorial https://www.codebrary.com/2021/07/hide-the-language-embedding-for-a-specific-language-in-sitecore-multilingual-site.html. And leave only the the domain name where you want to have a language Embedding